# Spring Jdbc atomicity with alter table

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I'm trying to write an equivalent of Rails data model evolution/rollback mechanism using Spring Jdbc.

Spring Jdbc transactionnal `insert/replace` works very well (DataSourceTransactionManager with PROPAGATION_REQUIRED under InnoDB mysql 5) :

```
// Transaction begins
getJdbcTemplate().execute("replace into aTable ...");
getJdbcTemplate().execute("wrong request");
getJdbcTemplate().execute("replace into aTable ...");
// none are commited
```

but `alter` doesn't :

```
// Transaction begins
getJdbcTemplate().execute("alter table aTable add column `columnForTest` ...");
getJdbcTemplate().execute("wrong request");
getJdbcTemplate().execute("alter table aTable add column `columnForTest` ...");
// the first alter is commited
```

Is there a way to achieve atomicity (all-or-none behavior) with `alter` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Adding DB columns during runtime is a *huge* datamodel design smell. Shouldn't you be using a link table? This way you just need to insert the "column name" and the desired associated data as a new row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE` (and other [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) operations) are usually non-transactional, depending on the database. Spring and JDBC have no control over this. If a non-transactional operation is performed inside a transaction, it will be performed non-transactionally.

So it comes down to the database, and how it is configured, rather than being an issue with the client.

Comment: Thanks, I will look in this direction.